# Highlight row if has duplicate value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello I have these columns 'name', 'email', 'username' and 'ip' how would I check or highlight table row in blade if records has same ip?

This is my controller

```
 $promo = Promo::with(['participants' => function ($q) {
            $q->orderBy('winner', 'desc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }])->find($id);
```

And this is my blade

```
@if($promos->participants->count() > 0)
    @foreach($promos->participants as $participant)
    <table>
      <tr class="align-middle">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>IP</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{$participant->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$participant->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$participant->username}}</td>
        <td>{{$participant->ip}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: You can make a _set_, and for every IP you meet, check if it's in that set, if it is, render it in bold, otherwise, render it normally. In both cases, add it to the set, so if it shows up again it would be in bold. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Do you have sample code for this? Cause what I want to achive is that if table row IP has same in other record IP then it will highlight row or something that make it special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to get duplicates by taking advantage of Larvel's collection and have them passed in view.

```
$ips = $promos->participants->pluck('ip');
$duplicateIps = $ips->duplicates()->unique()->all();
```

So in your blade you would just need to check

```
@if($promos->participants->isNotEmpty())
@foreach($promos->participants as $participant)
<table>
  <tr class="align-middle">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>IP</td>
  </tr>
  <tr @class(['duplicate-row' => in_array($participant->ip, $duplicateIps)]>
    <td>{{$participant->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$participant->email}}</td>
    <td>{{$participant->username}}</td>
    <td>{{$participant->ip}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
@endforeach
```

Comment: THere is an error to this line "<tr @class(['duplicate-row' => in_array($participant->ip, $duplicateIps)]>"

Comment: which laravel version you are using?

Comment: that is laravel 9's syntax, use `@if ` instead of `@class` there if your version doesn't support it.

Comment: I see, I am using 9

Comment: Okay, then what's the exact error?

Comment: Undefined variable $duplicateIps

Comment: You should know by now how to pass variable from controllers to views if you are using Laravel.  Pass `$duplicateIps` from controller to views like how you are passing `$promos` variable. It should work.

Comment: Yes I already did, and already find the error. There is no error now.

Comment: Is this code correct? @if(['duplicate-row' => in_array($participant->ip, $duplicateIps)]) @endif I just replace the class into if

Comment: no that's not correct, it should be `@if(in_array($participant->ip, $duplicateIps)) duplicate-row @endif`, if you are using laravel 9 that stick to `@class` it is more cleaner that way

Comment: I am using this now @class(['duplicate-row' => in_array($participant->ip, $duplicateIps)]) but it hightlighted all the rows into red

Comment: But is there a way to just highlight the duplicate one? I mean if there is a 3 same ip the 2 only should highlighted

Comment: You are amazing I am new at laravel heheh thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

> `$ipList` will store IPs when `foreach` runs and keeps checking whether they exist. If yes,  add class `duplicate-row` to the `<tr>`

```
$ipList = [];
@foreach($promos->participants as $participant)
  <tr class="align-middle @if(in_array($participant->ip, $ipList)) duplicate-row @endif">
    <td>{{$participant->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$participant->email}}</td>
    <td>{{$participant->username}}</td>
    <td>{{$participant->ip}}</td>
  </tr>
  @if(!in_array($participant->ip, $ipList))
    <?php array_push($ipList, $participant->ip); ?>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

In CSS you can add

```
.duplicate-row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I am having error "Undefined variable $ipList".

Comment: what there is no ` $ips` its `$ipList` check again

Comment: Yes, it says Undefined variable

Comment: it's there `$ipList = [];`. check properly.

Comment: Yes, same error. Should I need to put @php before $ipList = []; ?

Comment: I just copied your code.

Comment: @Ryan you need to wrap the **$ipList = [];** in php code so either **<?php $ipList = []; ?>** or **@php $ipList = []; @endphp**